# Get-Service command giving me the error Cannot open Service Control Manager on computer 'xx'. This operation might require other privileges

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-automation, azure-monitoring

I am trying to disable MicrosoftMonitoringAgent on VM. I am using Automation account system assigned managed identity which has virtual machine contributor role. I am executing the below command using runbook.

`Get-Service -Computer $vmName -Name $service`

I am getting the error
Cannot open Service Control Manager on computer 'xx'. This operation might require other privileges.

What permissions do I need or enable anything so the command works.

Comment: Hi @Narendra, The above you are getting due to Insufficient permission on Local VM, it may require Local Admin access for stopping the services in VM.

Comment: I used another way as well . I have service account which has access to local VM. when tried create a pssession using $session = New-PSSession -ComputerName $vmName -Credential $Credential.

Comment: I got this error The WinRM client cannot process the request. If the authentication scheme is different from Kerberos, or if the client computer is not joined to a domain, then HTTPS transport must be used or the destination machine must be added to the TrustedHosts configuration setting. Use winrm.cmd to configure TrustedHosts. Note that computers in the TrustedHosts list might not be authenticated. You can get more information about that by running the following command: winrm help config. For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.

Comment: To access a VM with local admin rights, you can assign the 'Virtual Machine Administrator Login' role to your system-assigned managed identity and verify the access.

Answer (score 0):

> Get-Service command giving me the error Cannot open Service Control Manager on computer 'xx'. This operation might require other privileges.

The error encountered is due to **insufficient permissions** on the `VM`. To stop the services on the VM, you may require `local admin` access.

The `Virtual Machine Contributor` role does not have local **admin access**. To obtain `local admin` privileges on a **VM**, you must assign both the `Virtual Machine Administrator Login` for `Local admin` and `Virtual Machine Contributor` role  for `Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/runCommand/write` permission, or alternatively, create a custom role with the required permissions.

```kotlin
 $scriptContent = @"
 Set-Service -name "AzureMonitorAgent" -startupType disabled
"@  
az vm run-command invoke --command-id RunPowerShellScript --name "Venkat-windows" -g 'Venkat' --scripts "$scriptContent"
```

**Output:**

[image]

After executing the script, the **AzureMonitorAgent** service has been successfully disabled on the `Azure VM`.

[image]

Reference: [Limiting access to Run Command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/run-command-managed#limiting-access-to-run-command)

[Virtual Machine Administrator Login](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles/compute#virtual-machine-administrator-login)